# Is there any relation between Bhairava (as Himself, not as Shiva) and Krishna/Vishnu? If so can someone please elaborate?

Tags: vaishnavism, tantra, shaivism, shaktism, bhairava

I have heard of the relation between different gods, however in the pantheon of Bhairavas, the association is mostly to do closely with manifestations of Shakti. Therefore it would be interesting to know of a link between the Bhairava and Vaishnava paths.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are many such examples like, Puri Jagannath is also considered as Bhagawan Bhairava along with Lord Krishna.

While describing the 51 Shaktipeeths, the Pīṭhanirṇaya, one of the most important Shakta texts described.:

> उत्कले नाभिदेशञ्च विरजाक्षेत्रमुच्यते । विमला सा महादेवी **जगन्नाथस्तु भैरवः** ॥१३॥
>
> 13.1: At Utkala, the portion of My Nabhi (Navel) fell, and the place is known as Viraja Kshetra (Viraja Kshetra), 13.2: The Mahadevi (Great Goddess) there is known as Vimala (literally meaning stainless, spotless, pure), and **the Bhairava there is Jagannatha (literally meaning the Lord of the World).**

Sri Ishwara Gita 1.32.:

> निरीक्ष्य ते **जगन्नाथं त्रिनेत्रं चन्द्रभूषणम्** । तुष्टबुर्हृष्टमनसो भक्त्या तं परमेश्वरम् ॥ १.३२॥
>
> Sages eulogise **Parmeshwar Shiva – who is Lord of all the worlds (Jagannatha), having three eyes and wearing the crescent moon on his head.**

As I have mentioned in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/53448/20968) of mine that Bhagawan Bhairava is an amsha, plus gana of Lord Shiva. And there are numerous Bhairavas.

Thus, When Lord Bhairava is Jagannatha, then Bhagawan Shiva is Jagannatha Natha viz the Lord of Jagannatha.

Sri Shivastakam.:

> प्रभुं प्राणनाथं विभुं विश्वनाथं **जगन्नाथ नाथं** सदानन्द भाजाम् ।
> भवद्भव्य भूतेश्वरं भूतनाथं, शिवं शङ्करं शम्भु मीशानमीडे ॥ 1 ॥
>
> I offer my Salutations to Lord Shiva Who is lord of "prana" (our lives), Lord Shiva who is Lord of Universe (vibhuṃ viśvanāthaṃ), **Lord Shiva who is even the Lord of the Lord of the Worlds (Vishnu/Bhairava) (jagannātha nāthaṃ),** Shiva who is Lord of all living beings, ghosts, and Lord of all.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, this is definitely interesting however it does leave the existence of Balabhadra and Subhadra unanswered. I suppose in this context Jagannatha being Bhairava is alike calling Shiva, Vishnu and Brahma as Purusha.. But does Bhairava, as the deity, and Jagannath also as a deity have a connection as individual beings?

Comment: U r welcome. You can check [this](https://m.facebook.com/?locale=ms_MY) fb post also. Plus, the story of Jagannatha is mentioned in Skanda Purana, which happened in dwapara ish yuga and daksha yahna is in satya yuga. This shows the oneness of Rudra-Vishnu. Mahabharata also says the same. And ur primary question was only asking about Bhairava and Vishnu/Krishna. So, my answer was like that only.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the information

Comment: U r welcome..... ...